# android adding MultiSelectListPreference

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-jetpack

I am trying to implement android jetpack preference for my settings screen.
everything is working good, when I click on MultiSelectListPreference, it shows the list of entries, but I have few questions,

1. why can't the entryValues be a integer-array? (string-array is working fine)
2. how to set default values? for eg: I want to set the second and third entry to be checked by default in the beginning.

here is a part of my pref.xml file

```
...
app:entries="@array/res_entries"
app:entryValues="@array/res_id_values"
app:defaultValue="@array/res_def_values" //this line is not working
...
```

If I set `res_id_values` in arrays.xml file to be a `integer-array`, then app is crashing.

My settingsFragment class extends PreferenceFragmentCompat and override `onCreatePreferences` and in it, I have written

```
setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref.xml, rootkey)
```

**EDIT**

My `res_entries` array :

```
<string-array name="res_entries">
  <item>apple</item>
  <item>Mango</item>
  <item>Guava</item>
</string-array>
```

My `res_id_values` array :

```
<string-array name="res_id_values">
  <item>1</item>
  <item>2</item>
  <item>12</item>
</string-array>
```

My `res_def_values` array :

```
<string-array name="res_def_values">
  <item>true</item>
  <item>false</item>
  <item>true</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: "why can't the entryValues be a integer-array?" -- because array resources are typed, and it is expecting a `String[]`, not an `int[]` or `Integer[]`. Plus, the saved values are `Set<String>`, not `Set<Integer>`.

Comment: @CommonsWare and how to set default values through xml?

Comment: If I am reading [this source](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/androidx-master-dev/preference/src/main/java/androidx/preference/MultiSelectListPreference.java#L190-L200) correctly, use `android:defaultValue` and have it point to another `<string-array>` resource.

Comment: I have tried doing it, but it's not working.
I did this
```
<string-array name="def_values">
  <item>true</item>
  <item>false</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Do those match strings in your `res_id_values` array?

Comment: @CommonsWare No, check my question again, I have edited it and added arrays used in MultiSelectListPreference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally, I solved it.
All thanks to @CommonsWare .

answer to my first question is that, we cannot use integer-array. Use a string array and store integer values in it. later when you get it, use Integer.parseInt().

now coming to second question, to store default value(let's say you want second and third item to be checked by default), use res_id_values in res_def_values. **Don't use true/false or 0/1 like me**.

eg: if in above question, If I want apple and guava to be checked by default, then my res_def_values will look like this:

```
<string-array name="res_def_values">
  <item>1</item>
  <item>12</item>
</string-array>
```